# New to django : Having a bug when creating models

Tags: python, django

hello 
i have an unknown error when creating a model class(check the code below ). im following the tutorial on the official django website , but it's not working for some reason, and i have been struggling over it for a while but with no results . is there anything wrong with what im doing ?

```
>>> class a(models.Model):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.1.2-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 52, in __new__
    kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: Where in the django tutorial do you encounter a class whose class name begins with a lowercase `a`?

Comment: in the tutorial it's (Person) not (a) , but that will not make much different .. class name is not the problem , it's with the (models.Model) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not define your models in command-line interpreter but use application file named `models.py` as the previous commenter said.
When django is processing your model it's trying to parse model's application name. In your case model has no any application. So just place your models in `myproject/myapplication/models.py` file and then you'll be able to create instances of models in command-line interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

The module containing your models should be named `myapp.models` from the Python interpreter's perspective.  This error means that it's resolving as just `models`.

First, the Python module containing this model needs to be inside of a [Django application folder](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models) which is on the PYTHONPATH.  Try using `python manage.py startapp` as explained in the tutorial.

If the model module is definitely in an application folder, make sure that the application folder *itself* is not part of the PYTHONPATH, only the project folder that contains it.

To help clarify, here's the context of the error in the django source:

```
        # Figure out the app_label by looking one level up.
        # For 'django.contrib.sites.models', this would be 'sites'.
        model_module = sys.modules[new_class.__module__]
        kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
```